# Trouble getting Pypar to work with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started using Pypar for parallel programming in Python.
I can get a simple script to run in parallel which is cool,
and I can get matplotlib to work as well,
but if I try to:

```
  import matplotlib
```

and run it through Pypar, I get:

```
  ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably WAY to late to answer this question. However, my guess is, that you simply did not install matplotlib on all you computational nodes...
So install and configure matplotlib on all the computers you are using for parallel computation and then try again.